# Android Studio:Null Pointer Excecption occured while working on TabLayout

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

[This is my code and the error that occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00zob.png)

I am a beginner and was trying to work on the tab layout. The app didn't give any error while compiling but crashes midway. My main activity code is as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TabLayout tabLayout= findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    TabItem t= findViewById(R.id.t1);
    final ViewPager viewPager= findViewById(R.id.pager);
   new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),4);


       tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
           @Override
           public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
               viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
           }

           @Override
           public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

           }

           @Override
           public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

           }

       });


}
```

Please help me as I have to submit this as my assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the declaration outside the oncreate function to make it global and seen by other methods, then do the initialization inside like this :

```
TabLayout tabLayout;
TabItem t;
ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
tabLayout= findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
t= findViewById(R.id.t1);
viewPager= findViewById(R.id.pager);
new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),4);
```

Comment: thanks for your help but doing this didn't help.My app still crashes abruptly with " Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$OnTabSelectedListener)' on a null object reference" as error